# The page is performing an async postback but ScriptManager.SupportsPartialRendering property is set to false

Tags: asp.net-ajax

How to fix the following exception?

> The page is performing an async postback but the   **ScriptManager.SupportsPartialRendering** property is set to false. Ensure that the property is set to true during an async postback.

This exception throws from  `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)`.

Comment: We're getting the error for iPad user agents: `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3`

Answer (score 8):

I found [this blog post here](http://dev.flauschig.ch/wordpress/?p=271) that speaks of a similar problem and mentions the default setting of respecting only 64 characters when caching the user agent:

```
<browserCaps userAgentCacheKeyLength="64" />
```

This element is placed inside `<system.web>` but might not be there since 64 is the default value according to [this MSDN library entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk9az15a.aspx).

How exactly ASP.NET determines the capabilities of certain browsers, I haven't yet investigated, but some hints can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343063%28d=lightweight,v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the remarks section.

Comment: In the referenced blog post it is recommended to use **256** as **64** is the default.

Comment: @AdamCaviness Thanks for your valuable comment. I somehow missed to point that out in my answer ;-)